# -JoinDomain parameter not working in Add-AzureProvisioningConfig

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to create a Windows VM in Azure and join it to the domain all in one step using the Azure PowerShell module. This is my script:

```
New-AzureVMConfig -Name $fileserver -Label $fileserver -InstanceSize Basic_A3 -ImageName $img -HostCaching ReadWrite -DiskLabel 'OS' -MediaLocation $medialoc `
| Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -WindowsDomain -JoinDomain $domjoin -Domain $dom -DomainUserName $domainuser -DomainPassword $domainpw -AdminUsername $adminPassword -Password $adminPassword `
| Set-AzureSubnet 'Dynamic1' `
| New-AzureVM -ServiceName $cloudSvcName -VNetName $vnet -verbose -waitforboot
```

The error i'm getting is as follows:

*New-AzureVM : BadRequest: Invalid domain join information specified. Ensure that the JoinDomain setting is specified, and that either the Credentials or Provisioning setting is specified.  See the
Windows Automated Installation Kit documentation for more information.*

If I take out these params:

```
-WindowsDomain -JoinDomain $domjoin -Domain $dom -DomainUserName $domainuser -DomainPassword $domainpw -AdminUsername $adminPassword -Password $adminPassword `
```

and replace them with these (removing the join domain stuff):

```
-Windows -AdminUserName "localadmin" -Password $adminPassword
```

I get no errors and the machine provisions just fine without domain joining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this was a stupid mistake. I had $dom set to "mydomain" and $domainuser set to "mydomain\user". $domain user should have been "user".